# UImage error in Android Kernel compilation

Tags: android, gcc, kernel, boot, u-boot

When I compile the amlogic kernel I get an error like this;

```
make: *** [out/target/product/g18/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/arch/arm/boot/uImage] Error 2
```

first I do;

```
-->export PATH="/home/infoteks-sba/opt/arm-2010q1/bin:$PATH"
-->export PATH="/home/infoteks-sba/opt/arm-eabi-4.6/bin:$PATH"
-->export PATH="/home/infoteks-sba/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin:$PATH"
-->export PATH="/home/infoteks-sba/opt/arm-2013.11/bin:$PATH"
-->export PATH="/home/infoteks-sba/opt/arc-eabi/bin:$PATH"
-->export PATH="/home/infoteks-sba/opt/eldk-5.4/armv7a/sysroots/i686-eldk-linux/usr/bin:/home/infoteks-sba/opt/eldk-5.4/armv7a/sysroots/i686-eldk-linux/usr/bin/armv7a-vfp-neon-linux-gnueabi:$PATH"
-->export PATH="/home/infoteks-sba/opt/ndk:$PATH"
-->export ARCH="arm"
-->export CROSS_COMPILE="arm-eabi-4.6-"
-->cd /AnroidKernelBuild
-->. build/envsetup.sh
-->lunch
list select number 32 (g18-eng)
-->make -j8
```

I tried them on my research;

```
*export CROSS_COMPILE="arm-eabi-"
*export CROSS_COMPILE="/home/infoteks-sba/opt/arm-eabi-4.6-"
*make -j8 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/infoteks-sba/opt/arm-eabi-4.6-
*make -j8 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-
*make -j8 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/infoteks-sba/opt/arm-eabi-4.6-
```

I'll give you all the logs on the link. How can I fix this error? Can you help me?
Link(while CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-) = https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wGgVjQ9Dn7/

**After correcting the errors;**

new error;

```
make: *** [vmlinux] Error 2
make: *** [out/target/product/g18/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/arch/arm/boot/uImage] Error 2
```

Comment: Look for lines containing "error:" - these are **actual errors**.

Comment: I solved them.
new bugs;make[2] ***[vmlinux] Error 1make: *** [out/target/product/g18/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/arch/arm/boot/uImage] Error 2

Comment: Again, message `make: *** [...] Error` is not useful in debugging the problem. This message just tells that some error(s) has occured **before**. You need to find actual error messages in the log.

Comment: After you said, I edited the errors in the diary.
The part that writes the error(Hata) is with vmlinux. The last log is as follows; https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hPDfdPHhpS/